# Deadlock in partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server

A SQL Server table has multiple partitions.Processes run in parallel for accessing different partitions. Deadlock happens between an update process and a delete process even though both access different partition of the same table and the process Id for delete becomes the deadlock victim.As per the deadlock graph delete process acquires a U lock and the update process acquires IU lock and hence the deadlock.

How to resolve this and attain smooth parallelism.

Comment: Post the queries and deadlock graph. The fact the table is partitioned doesn't affect deadlocks. Somehow, somewhere two queries tried to use rows that were locked by the other.

Comment: As for parallelism, you already use it. Partitions have nothing to do with performance they are a data management technique. The only thing they speed up is partition switching and deletion. Your RAID array already processes requests in parallel. SQL Server already parallelizes expensive queries. Different connections use different threads.

Comment: If operations (like update) that involve more than 5000 rows, the lock escalation on the table might pop from row/page to table, even with partitions.

Comment: The appropriate place for such a question would be dba.stackexchange.com but the answer would be the same - missing information, partitions aren't a performance feature. They'd be more vocal about the second part though